# how to get details from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql

In MySql database have `AM_COURSE` table in that

```
cId      CourseName   course_desc
  101          java        sometext...
  102          mysql       sometext....
   :
```

`AM_USER` in that

```
 uid   name 
1001  Ram
1002  pavan
```

`AM_INTER` in that

```
  id   uid     cid
  1    1001    101
  2    1001    102
  3    1002    101
```

`AM_TIMETABLE` table in that

```
UserId        Date_Time
 101        2012-08-08 04:00:00 
 102        2012-08-15 10:00:00
 103        2012-08-18 09:00:00
 104        2012-08-24 05:00:00
```

My Question is, i'm passing start-date and end-date and `CourseName` then i want to get details like userId,name,coursename,course_desc in that way i wrote query

```
    SELECT  a.cid,a.course_desc,c.name 
    FROM  
    AM_COURSE a,AM_USER c INNER JOIN AM_TIMETABLE b ON a.S_ID = b.COURSE_ID WHERE
    a.Name = 'java' 
    AND 
    b.Date_Time BETWEEN '2012-08-07 00:00:00' AND '2012-08-20 00:00:00'
```

but i'm getting error  `please help`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INNER JOIN keyword returns rows when there is at least one match in both tables.

**MySQL INNER JOIN clause**

The MySQL INNER JOIN clause matches rows in one table with rows in other tables and allows you to query rows that that contain columns from both tables.

The MySQL INNER JOIN clause an optional part of the SELECT statement. It appears immediately after the FROM clause.

Before using MySQL INNER JOIN clause, you have to specify the following criteria:

First, you have to specify the main table that appears in the FROM clause.
Second, you need to specify the tables that you want to join with the main table, which appear in the INNER JOIN clause. Theoretically, you can join a table with many tables. However, for a better query performance, you should limit the number of tables to join.
Third, you need to specify the join condition or join predicate. The join condition appears after the keyword ON of  the INNER JOIN clause. The join condition is the rule for matching rows between the main table and the other tables.

**Example**

```
SELECT  c.cid, c.course_desc, user.name FROM AM_COURSE c
INNER JOIN AM_INTER inter on inter.cid = c.cid
INNER JOIN AM_USER user on user.uid = inter.uid
INNER JOIN AM_TIMETABLE tt ON inter.cid = tt.UserId
WHERE c.Name = 'coursename' AND tt.Date_Time BETWEEN '2011-08-12' AND '2012-08-12'
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT  course.cid, course.course_desc, user.name
FROM AM_COURSE course
INNER JOIN AM_INTER inter on inter.cid = course.cid
INNER JOIN AM_USER user on user.uid = inter.uid
INNER JOIN AM_TIMETABLE tt ON inter.cid = tt.UserId
WHERE course.Name = 'java' 
AND tt.Date_Time BETWEEN '2012-08-07' AND '2012-08-20'
```