# How to get date in multiple tables in MySql database?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get details from multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829034/how-to-get-details-from-multiple-tables)

In MySql database have five tables

```
Course

c_id         name     course_desc
101           java       sometext…..

User

u_id       firstname      Address
201          ram               Hyd

SkillSet

S_id     c_id     u_id    experience    course_content
301      101       201       2                          somtext…

Timetable

T_id      c_id    u_id     date_time            class_duration(H)
401        101      201   2012-08-08              2

Intrest

I_id        t_id      u_id
501         401       201
```

My Question is, i'm passing start-date and end-date and Name(courseName) then i want to get details like

```
Name(courseName),course_desc,firstname


select course.c_id,course.course_desc,user.firstname
    from COURSE course
    inner join SKILLSET skill on skill.course_id=course.c_id
    inner join USER user on user.c_id=skill.u_id
    inner join TIMETABLE tt on skill.c_id=tt.u_id
    where course.name='java'
    and tt.date_time BETWEEN '2012-08-07 00:00:00' AND '2012-08-20 00:00:00'
```

it is showing error.. please help me…. ...

Comment: please use the join to get your require field and than if you have problem in the result then after ask to the people..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For name you have to write a query like this.

```
select name from Course c,SkillSet s where c.cid= s.cid.
```

I think you get the process how the joins work. Find the common columns in different tables(in this case, cid is the common column). Then you join tables and you can get an attribute as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you're linking in the `inter` or `skill` tables:

```
INNER JOIN Skillset on skill.cid = course.cid
                       ^^^^^
INNER JOIN AM_USER user on user.uid = inter.uid
                                      ^^^^^
```

and as a general tip, if you say you get an error, it's INCREDIBLY helpful to actually say what the error is. Without the error text, we're just guessing and you're less likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: sorry... please help me to write a query..please..please...

Comment: That's not how this site works. You had the query, and now you've ninja-edited it out. We're not here to do your job for you, but will help fix code you've written. I've shown you two obvious problems with the query, so fix those... and tell us what the error you got actually was. We've got better things to do than guess at what the problem is, especially when you start hiding things on us.

Comment: Actually i'm trying all the possible way's to get those fields but some how missing to build query and i'm using Join's concept but i'm asking is their any better way to solve it...